# ELSIF not working inside trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this simple trigger that checks to see if a RentalType is either 'M' or 'B' if it is lower case it sets it to upper. If it is neither of those It will throw an exception but for some reason when I update the table with a letter that is not M or B it does nothing.

PS the lowercase to UPPER works fine.

Here is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Validate_Type
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RentalAgreement
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    InvalidValue EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(InvalidValue, -20750);
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.RentalType = 'm' OR :NEW.RentalType = 'b' THEN
        :NEW.RentalType := UPPER(:NEW.RentalType);
    ELSIF :NEW.RentalType != 'M' OR :NEW.RentalType != 'B' THEN
        RAISE InvalidValue;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN InvalidValue THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Rental Type ' || :NEW.RentalType);
END;
/
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `TRIGGER` is handling the `EXCEPTION` raised by you but it is not being passed on to the DML that triggered it. So, the `RentalType`  column gets inserted normally.

So, either *remove* the `EXCEPTION` block OR *add* a simple `RAISE` statement in the `EXCEPTION`

Also, looks like

```
:NEW.RentalType != 'M' OR :NEW.RentalType != 'B'
```

will always be true.

Did you mean `:NEW.RentalType != 'M' AND :NEW.RentalType != 'B'`?

Comment: Better: `IF :NEW.RentalType in ('b', 'm')` in one place, and `:NEW.RentalType not in ('B', 'M')` in the other.

Comment: "... will always be true." OR NOT. **Quiz**: When might it not be true?  :-)

Comment: @mathguy : may if der's `null` ? . But It's sleeping time now in my country.. so, I'll wait for the answer till tomorrow.

Comment: Right - if :NEW.RentalType is NULL, the logical condition (with OR) will evaluate to UNKNOWN. Which is OK (the condition will "fail", as it should); but the condition wont' do what the OP needs when the new value is NOT null.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the explanation. Where' s my prize ?? :-)